# How to write nice and clean Go package?

Tags: go, package

I try to implement Sparse sets from this [article](https://programmingpraxis.com/2012/03/09/sparse-sets/) in Go and make it into a package. In early implementation, the API is clean and minimal with only exported type `Sparse` and exported method `Insert`, `Delete`, `Has`, `Union`, `Intersection`, `Clear`, and `Len`, pretty much only basic sets operation.

Later on, I want to add new functionality, sets that can reserve an element automatically (lets call it `AutoSparse`). If `Sparse` have `Insert(k int)` which insert k into sets, `AutoSparse` have `Reserved()` reserved an available element. If I have `{0 1 2 4 5}` in `AutoSparse`, when i call `Reserve()` it must add 3, not 6 so now it become `{0 1 2 4 5 3}`. Here's the implementation at [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HlHEMakEgat).

As you can see, in order to maintain which element to added into sets, it doesn't add new field in the `struct` and I want to keep it like that.

My Question is how to add that new functionality to my package without adding new exported type `AutoSparse` to keep the API clean and minimal?

This is what i already try:

1. I can use `interface` to hide implementation but function signature is different, one use `Insert(k int)`, the other use `Reserve()`, even if I use name `Insert()` it still different, or should I use `Insert(k int)` but didn't use `k` at all? it can but it's awkward.
2. I can't use the same `struct` to implement this because once you Use `Reserve()` to add element, you can't use `Insert(k int)` because it will messed up the reserved element, even `Delete` and `Clear` is different.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `k... int` as parameter.

```
func (sparse Sparse) Insert(k... int) error {
    if len(k) == 0 {
        // first case
        return nil
    } else if len(k) == 1 {
        // second case
        return nil
    } else {
        return errors.New("Too many arguments")
    }
}
```